# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' offline

Tags: spring

Hi I have been working on this old project offline with Spring framework 3.2 and everything is working fine.

The error "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'" only happened when i copied the project folders to another location and import them using the same workspace.

If i go online, then the error disappear. Any idea how can i make it work offline?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
```

All the spring library are located in the Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your configuration looks to an external source for xml schema definitions. i.e.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
```

You will have to store and access all of these definitions locally.